# How does one properly lay out a standalone system service in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've recently become interested in writing some system services for OS X but since I have no application to advertise the services under I must resort to writing standalone system services. Apple's documentation on System Services is spartan as it is, but its documentation on standalone services is non-existant.

What I have thus far is an Xcode project built from the bundle package, with the two sources `HashifyService.h` and `HashifyService.m`. Here is the test code I have:

```
- (void) doServiceWork:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
            userData:(NSString *)userData
                 error:(NSString **)error {
  NSLog(@"Actually in the service now");
  NSString *pboardString;
  NSArray *types;

  NSLog(@"do test magic service! (pboard: %@, types: %@)", pboard, [pboard types]);


  NSString* outputString = @"It Worked";
  types = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType];
  [pboard declareTypes:types owner:nil];
  [pboard setString:outputString forType:NSStringPboardType];
  [outputString release];
  return;
}
```

and this is the `NSServices` entry in my `Info.plist`:

```
<dict>
<key>NSMenuItem</key>
<dict>
    <key>Menu item title</key>
    <string>HashifyTest</string>
</dict>
<key>NSMessage</key>
<string>doServiceWork</string>
<key>NSPortName</key>
<string>HashifyService</string>
<key>NSReturnTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
</array>
<key>NSSendTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

I then build the service bundle and place it in `~/Library/Services/` where it is appropriately detected and I am given the option to use the service. Upon activating the service, however, an error occurs and is logged to Console:

```
..../Hashify.service/Contents/MacOS/Hashify: cannot execute binary file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this tutorial. Basically, you need to specifiy your bundle's extension as ".services" and add a plist key that prevents the app from getting focus. http://www.notesfromandy.com/2013/04/05/writing-a-service-bundle/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `main()` function. That should register the service using `NSRegisterServicesProvider()` and enter the run loop. That is in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html).